# Gives empty address when using google places api

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I am trying to retrieve the exact address from the given lat/lng using the following url,

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?&radius=1000&sensor=false&key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx&location=13.24299231,80.30418218

The response JSON gives an array of results, the first object in the array has no address in the vicinity field.  I would like to know if there is any other alternative for getting the address or is there any workaround to retrieve the exact address of the given lat/lng.

FYI - I prefer using Google Places API for address retrival.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the vicinity contains no data, then use the `formatted_address` or build the address by using the `address_components` array.

[Here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_details_responses) you will find a description of the response object returned.